# How to determine reference reachability in java

Tags: java, reference, weak-references, soft-references

In Java, how to determine reference reachability in some complicated cases such as reference chain?

Suppose in the following example, `str` is the referent of a software reference `sr` and `sr` is a referent of a weak reference `wr`.

```
String str = "abc";
SoftReference<Object> sr = new SoftReference<>(str);
WeakReference<Object> wr = new WeakReference<>(sr);
str = null;
sr = null;
```

Then in this case, what is the reachability of `str`? According the Java doc: `An object is softly reachable if it is not strongly reachable but can be reached by traversing a soft reference.` In  the case, `str` can be reached by traversing `wr` and `sr`, which means the traversing goes through a soft reference. Can I say `str` is softly reachable? But following the section ***Chains of reference objects*** in this [doc](http://pawlan.com/monica/articles/refobjs/), it seems the `str` is weakly reachable.

Comment: Assuming that `str` and `sr` are no longer in scope (since for example `str` is a strong reference to the string "abc") then the string "abc" is only weakly reachable because the only way from a strong reference (`wr`) to the string traverses a `WeakReference`. The string becomes unreachable as soon as the garbage collector clears all weak references - that it did not yet clear the soft references doesn't matter.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I am sorry that I forgot to set `str` to be null in the example...

Comment: @ThomasKläger “the string "abc" is only weakly reachable because the only way from a strong reference (wr) to the string traverses a WeakReference” - But it also traverse a SoftReference. Following the java doc, it seems it should be a SoftReference? I am a little bit confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reference to be *softly reachable* the soft reference itself must be either *strongly reachable* or *softly reachable*.

You can think of these references as a chain: at one end is an anchor point (a garbage collection root: for example a reference in an active thread or a class field). At the other end is your object.

The whole chain cannot be stronger than any of the elements in between, because the whole chain breaks as soon as any of the elements breaks and at that moment you loose the access to your object.

The garbage collector clears *weak references* before it clears *soft references* and therefore *weak references* are weaker than *soft references*.

That means with your example: as soon as the garbage collector clears the weak reference to the `SoftReference` object your object / string is inaccessible and will be garbage collected, **even if** the garbage collector does not yet clear the soft reference objects.

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: “does not yet clear” is a misleading phrase here. When the garbage collector decides to clear the weak reference, the `SoftReference` becomes unreachable and hence, will never be cleared. So no “yet”.